# weird select drop down box error. content spilling out on page

Tags: php

Weird issue the country names are no longer being listed in the select dropdown box they're just spilling out all over the page. can anyone spot the coding error that is causing it?

```
echo "<select name=recordcountry style='width: 136px;'>";
//echo "<option value=$country selected=selected>-- Select --</option>";
echo "<option ". ($data['recordcountry'] == "" ? 'selected=selected>-- Select --</option>' : 'value="' .$data['recordcountry']. '" selected=selected');

$group1 = '<optgroup label=Common>';
$group2 = '<optgroup label=Alphabetically>';
$group = mysql_query("SELECT country, grouping, p_order FROM mast_country 
WHERE grouping IN ('1','2') ORDER BY p_order");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($group))
{
  if ($row['grouping'] == '1')
  {
       $group1 .= '<option value="'.$row['country'].'">'.
            $row['country'].'</option>';
  }
  else
  {
       $group2 .= '<option value="'.$row['country'].'">'.
            $row['country'].'</option>';
  }
    $group1 .= '</otpgroup>';
    $group2 .= '</otpgroup>';

    echo $group1;
    echo $group2;
    echo "</select>";
}
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML it produces?

Comment: You should really start quoting ALL your tag arguments, not only those containing whitespace!

Comment: @user18248 all the country names are just being listed outside of the dropdown box. I fixed the </otpgroup> or </optgroup> but that did not correct it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `</optgroup>`, not `</otpgroup>`.

```
echo "<option ". ($data['recordcountry'] == "" ? 'selected=selected>-- Select --</option>' : 'value="' .$data['recordcountry']. '" selected=selected');
```

makes no sense, too. It is highly confusing and you are not adding `</option>`.
Here's a better version:

```
echo '<option value="'.$data['recordcountry'].'"'.($data['recordcountry'] ? '' : ' selected="selected"').'>'.($data['recordcountry'] ? $data['recordcountry'] : '--Select--').'</option>';
```

Or even better, split it into two lines and use an IF statement:

```
if($data['recordcountry'])
    echo '<option value="'.$data['recordcountry'].'">'.$data['recordcountry'].'</option>';
else
    echo '<option value="" selected="selected">--Select--</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line.

```
echo "<option ". ($data['recordcountry'] == "" ? 'selected=selected>-- Select --</option>' : 'value="' .$data['recordcountry']. '" selected=selected');
```

No end tag is added when `$data['recordcountry'] == ""`. Should be something like this i think.

```
echo "<option ". ($data['recordcountry'] == "" ? 'selected=selected>-- Select --</option>' : 'value="' .$data['recordcountry']. '" selected='selected'>" . $data['recordcountry'] . "</option>");
```

Edit: And what ThiefMaster said